# What is the Advantages and Disadvantages of digital signatures over HMAC?

Tags: signature, hmac

I want know the advantages of using digital signatures over HMAC for message by message authentication.

I know that HMACs are inexpensive to implement compared to DS, but DS provides a very strong security also uses more processing power. Are these two the main differences?

Answer (score 0):

Digital signatures provide [non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation), which is one of the basic principles of [information security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security), and HMACs do not (since the key in HMAC is known both to the sender and the receiver).

And then of course the points you mentioned also apply.